# Can I add ony specific WCF endpoints to a .NET 2.0 project as web references?

Tags: wcf, .net-2.0, web-reference

I'm developing a .NET 2.0 client application that needs to connect to a WCF service. I add a web reference to a basicHttpBinding WCF service that we've developed and VS creates the proxy class and the config paraphenalia which is fine. The problem is that I only want to use a small fraction of the methods that the WCF service implements and not carry around the extra implementations that the client app doesn't need.

I was thinking of creating a different basicHttpBinding endpoint and put the methods there. Is there a way for only one endpoint of a WCF service to be referenced by a .NET 2.0 project?

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a web reference to a service, you always get all the service methods. It's the service (implementation) that defines the scope of what ends up in the WSDL.

The only option to limit the scope of the method your client generates would be to create a second WCF service on the backend, which only implements those few methods that you want in your client - just having a second endpoint won't really help.